# Получить последовательность каждый член которой равен -1, 0, или 1

Tags: математика, числа, системы-счисления, арифметика

Есть некоторое число  , его нужно разложить в последовательность  0 , ...,  ,  каждый член которой равен -1, 0, или 1, такую, что  =⋅3^+...+1⋅3+0  ( ≠0 )

Есть идеи как можно это реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Короче, если это 3 в степени n - а я в этом уверен :) - то задача решается так: переводим число в троичную систему счисления. Получается число с цифрами 0, 1 и 2.

Идем от младшего разряда к старшему, если встречаем 2 - заменяем на -1 и прибавляем к разряду старше единицу (по сути заменяя 2 = 3 - 1). Рекурсивно повторяем...

Например, 743. В троичной системе - 1000112. Последнюю двойку заменяем на -1 (буду изображать как i - просто чтоб отличать...) Получаем 100012i. Переходим к двойке слева. Та же картина - 10002ii. И опять... 1001iii. Это и есть искомое представление:

1*3^6+1*3^2+3+2=729+9+3+2=743  (1000112)
1*3^6+1*3^3-3^2-3-1=729+27-9-1=743  (1001iii)

Comment: думаю, стоило упомянуть название рекомендуемой книги (вероятно, это «Депман И.Я. - Меры и метрическая система»): средствами обхода блокировок пользуются далеко не все.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ладно, удалил, чтоб вопросов не вызывало...